# Add PNG image to picturebox dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, png, picturebox, dynamic

I can't add a PNG image that contains alpha chanel into a picturebox dynamically by code because it always replace the transparent area with the black color. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the picturebox's backcolor to transparent?  I have used PNGs with transparency before, as long as that was set....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the back color of the control to transparent?